.exe builded from Pyinstaller show OSError22 Invalid argument when copy file to network drive
I have try to copy file to network drive wiht ip it's show OSError22 Invalid argument if I run through .exe file with builed from pyinstaller
below is a code i use to copy file and error from this case. where 192.168.2.200 is ip of host drive
import shutil

file_name = name
destination_path = f"//192.168.2.200/store_data/{name_file}"
src_path = file_name
shutil.copyfile(src_path, destination_path)

enter image description here
If i run above code with python script like "python main.py" it works properly.
I also try to mapped drive(Drive letter such as S:) the results are the same with "python main.py" it works properly but when run through .exe builded from pyinstaller it shows "File Not found".
Does anyone know how to fix or work around this if i want to run via pyinstaler.exe instead of pure python script.
